# Any free software for opening DCM files

Tags: windows, vector-graphics, photography

How can I open [.DCM files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DICOM) for free. I can use [Imagemagic](http://www.imagemagick.org/) to open a single .dcm file [shows a single image] but it doesn't show the combination of .dcm files as a single item[not an interactive image] . I hope I make sense by that.

I am trying to read some [MRI images](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_resonance_imaging) and I am looking for a software which shows MRI files just like the sample MRI on WIKI.